# spark submit giving "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Some.value()Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to do a spark submit to check the compatibility with some simple scala code

```
println("Hi there")

val p = Some("pop")
p match {
  case Some(a) => println("Matched " + a)
  case _ => println("00000009")
}
```

scala version: 2.12.5
spark version: 2.4.6

currently after building and running the jar through spark-submit 2.4.7
it gives:

```
Hi there
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Some.value()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at MangoPop$.main(MangoPop.scala:9)
    at MangoPop.main(MangoPop.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

From maven, it seems spark 2.4.6 supports scala 2.12
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core

But when running with spark submit 3.0.2, it runs fine.

What am i missing with spark 2.4.6 
(also tried with spark 2.4.7, even though there is no actual spark dependencies/code, only scala)

Running spark submit as

```
~/Downloads/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$  ./spark-submit --class=Test myprojectLocation..../target/scala-2.12/compatibility-check_2.12-0.1.jar
```

```
/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ ./spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.7
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.11.12, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_282
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user prashant on 2020-09-08T05:22:44Z
Revision 14211a19f53bd0f413396582c8970e3e0a74281d
Url https://prashant:Sharma1988%235031@gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

also tried 2.4.6 downloading from
https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.6/

but could not find for scala 2.12

Can we also explicitly mention which scala version to use when doing spark-submit or spark-shell as in the configuration it seems it supports both but it used the lower one, ie 2.11

This is load-spark-env.cmd file

```
rem Setting SPARK_SCALA_VERSION if not already set.

set ASSEMBLY_DIR2="%SPARK_HOME%\assembly\target\scala-2.11"
set ASSEMBLY_DIR1="%SPARK_HOME%\assembly\target\scala-2.12"
```

Comment: Change scala version to 2.11.8, and make sure that you main class is defined in build.sbt

Comment: Yes **Spark** `2.4.6` could be cross-compiled with **Scala** `2.12` but an installation has to pick one exact version and it is very probably that your installation is using **Scala** `2.11`

Comment: Hi @NassereddineBelghith , actually i were to using scala 2.12

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez , I downloaded spark 2.4.7 from https://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-4-7-released.html . but 2.4.7 also seems it supports scala 2.12, btw which installation you were refering to ?

Comment: @supernatural that one you downloaded and installed using **spark-submit**, run **spark-shell** that will show you which exact **Scala** version it is using, ideally you should use that one even the bugfix version _(the third number)_. - BTW, if you just want to learn **Spark** I would recommend just running it from **sbt** instead of installing it in your computer, that way it will use the **Scala** version you set in your `build.sbt` file

Comment: spark-shell 2.4.7 is showing 2.11.12, but in the documentation it shows it supports scala 2.12 and also Some(x) is available in scala 2.12 or 2.11 too , even inside the spark-shell, but after packaging and running why does it throws that error

Comment: @supernatural **Scala** is NOT binary compatible between minor versions, only between patch versions. As such, code compiled using `2.11.12` can be run by any `2.11` version but not for any `2.12` or `2.10` or `2.13` version. - **Spark** is cross-compiled for both `2.11` and `2.12` which means you can download binaries that were compiled either with `2.11` or `2.12` but each binary can only support one **Scala** version. - Yes, previous versions of **Scala** also had `Some` and their usage may be sourcecode compatible, but their binary representation is not.

Comment: Can you do `spark-submit --version` and add it to your question? Can you also include how you spark-submit the scala code?

Comment: yeah updated @JacekLaskowski

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez where can i get the binaries for spark 2.4.6 compatible for scala 2.12, as couldnt get it so far https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.6/ , the existing one is without hadoop

Comment: Can we explicitly mention which scala version to use while doing spark-submit or spark-shell from the supported versions ?

Comment: No you can not select which version to use for a `spark-submit` because again, I repeat, each binary of **Spark** was compiled and used a single version of **Scala**. You can not change that, you have to change the binary of **Spark** to use a different **Scala** version. No idea where you can get the appropriate binaries, in the end for the **Spark** community it was irrelevant to support newer versions of **Scala**, they are a **Java** project whose majority of users are **Python** programmers. Also, in real life one usually depends on cloud vendors to provide clusters and those use `2.11`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the runtime version of Spark is *"Using Scala version 2.11.12"* while your code (`MangoPop$.main(MangoPop.scala:9)`) uses *"scala version: 2.12.5"*.

Make sure the build and runtime versions of Spark are at the same Scala version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by creating a new conda enviroment from scratch.

In my Spark project I had issues before with Scala 11 and switched to Scala 12. Presumably, the dependencies and libraries got messed up in this process somewhere.